# TeX warnings about non closed groups and LaTeX editors (that not warning)

Tags: editors, grouping

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\bgroup
Test 1

{
\bfseries
Test 2

\begingroup
Test 3
{

Test 4

\end{document}
```

After running `pdflatex` through my kile editor, I don't get even a simple message or warning in the output (as I see it inside kile's "Log and Messages" window) but in the log file or by runing pdflatex I can see:

```
### simple group (level 4) entered at line 14 ({)
### semi simple group (level 3) entered at line 12 (\begingroup)
### simple group (level 2) entered at line 8 ({)
### simple group (level 1) entered at line 5 ({)
### bottom level</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
mbx10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.p
fb>
```

I was expecting at least a warning on my editor. So my question is:

1. Which editors reproduce this "no warning" problem?
2. Is it a bug we have to report for every editor?

Comment: the `simple group` message *is* the warning.  it's issued by tex, not latex.  i don't have a copy at hand, but i'm sure it's documented in the texbook.  i also covered it in a talk at tug 2017; the slides are available from a link at the tug 2017 web site, accessible at `tug.org/tug2017`.  the paper appears in tugboat 38:2 (accessible only to members at the moment); it's much different from the preprint, so if you're not a member, the slides are better.

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton. For next visitors the slide is slide 14 here: http://www.gust.org.pl/bachotex/2017-pl/presentations/bbeeton-1-2017.pdf. It discussing about the good practice of closing any open group earlier, and at that slide talks about debugging of such "warnings". I also found there that a "good editor" had to provide functionality (like highlighting or may be warnings as far as I can understand it) about such groups... I tested on kile and LyX (kile just dont closing the highlighted area)... Both showed nothing on compilation. So, is this a feature of "no good editors" ?

Comment: @koleygr Kile is hopeless with TeX stuff, at least in LaTeX files. Reliably hopeless. It certainly won't recognise those as warnings.

Comment: Thanks @cfr for the information... If anyone of you find the same problem in other editors you can add them in comments to include them in my post since it is an editor specific problem as far as I can understand now... (I can confirm the problem on kile and lyx right now...)

Comment: it's not really a bug but of course it would not be an unreasonable feature request for any editor. TeX makes it tricky as it doesn't change the program exit status or use the word `Warning` or write to stderr rather than stdout or do anything else to give any indication that anything is wrong, so the editor would need to look for that specific text and show it in their view of editors/warnings.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you are right, But it seems easy to be added if I suppose all these warnings start with `###` (general for TeX warnings) or with `### semi group` or `### simple group`

Comment: These warnings are issued at the very last moment when TeX is about to end the job and the normal warning methods are no longer available; the `###` prefix is typical of extended logging information, which TeX switches to in order the user is able to find the mistakes. Something similar happens if you forget to close a conditional.

Comment: @egreg Yes, but the most of the editors gives you a warning or an error for unclosed conditionals... Why to not prompt  for unclosed groups too? I think that they use the pdflatex output anyway and these warnings can easily be included in their behavior towards user interface.

Comment: @koleygr -- how do you know where a group is supposed to end?  many groups last intentionally for a very long time, even over multiple chapters.  really, the only time it's definite that groups are still open is at `\end{document}` (or just `\end` in the case of plain tex).  it's better to get a "late" message than a bogus one.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I never said that I know where a group is supposed to end. And I agree with your sentences one by one. Nor even a conditional I know where have to end.... This is exactly what I say too... That the editors can give this late message than not giving it at all and letting it hidden inside the log file. I just saying that editors can (and would be better to) include these tex messages in their interface with the user.

Comment: @koleygr -- ah, okay.  i use raw emacs, so i never assumed that the editor would help with *that* sort of debugging.  i have instead learned to study the log file to find out everything that it can tell me.  (latex didn't exist when i undertook to learn tex; i had to learn tex and emacs at the same time.  however, i also learned that the first thing one should define is one's user interface for a tex job, and only then run amok.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I use kile but using emacs too. I just haven't found a feature on emacs to highlight the content between braces (groups)... And this keeps me stucked to kile for latex but all my other programming is on emacs. When I started latex on 1998 I used emacs too... I am still thinking of going back to emacs... and made gave a try  with my way: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378380/gnome-see-basic-emacs-commands-in-background-image/378449#378449... Thanks again!

Comment: @koleygr -- with emacs in "latex" mode, if you click on a closing delimiter (not just a brace, parens too), it will flash the opener of the pair, or if it's not on the screen, it will show the opener with context, and maybe (i don't remember) the line number.  at this point in my existence, i can't change; emacs is in my fingers, and with any other conventions, i proliferate errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups inside `LaTeX` and `TeX` is something that sometimes could be complicated and could even not be closed at all or closed after the expansion of a command somehow complicated and thus only `TeX` would discover on exiting that one or more groups are still open. (Thanks to all of the members that commented and made me understand this fact and to this community in general that helped me see some examples like the described)

In my opinion a good editor should provide all of the output of the compilation proces and of course the user should gain the ability to understand as more messages as possible and be able to debug easier hes/her code.

In order to not leave the question unanswered I am adding here the editors that tested till now and didn't gave output in their interface about the non closed groups (that TeX already provided) but have left them hidden inside the log file.

1. Overleaf (online editor that also forces the compilation)
2. Kile (that you have to open the log file in order to find TeX output)
3. LyX (as far as I remember it was giving no information at all and I have to open the log file too -but used just two or three times-)
4. TeXworks??? (not sure now)

Anyone is welcome to edit and add/remove editors

PS: Finally I realized that this forgotten question should deal with hiding "importand" `TeX` information from the user interface to be more useful/general and to offer something in this community.